# Backup strategy

Tags: backup

When backing up Ubuntu 12.04 is it necessary to backup system files outside of the home folder?  I have had a GRUB installation become corrupted by a subsequent update.  I need a strategy to recover from errant updates.  That is, to roll back my updates.

Answer (score 4):

I won't speak on whether or not you need to backup system files but if you want roll back on your entire system you could do something crazy with [bup](http://github.com/bup/bup) and dd.  We do something similar with our databases to give use almost infinite roll back capabilities.  But this is obviously on a smaller scale.

> bup is a program that backs things up.  It's short for "backup." Can you
> believe that nobody else has named an open source program "bup" after all
> this time?  Me neither.
>
> #### bup has a few advantages over other backup software:
>
> - It uses a rolling checksum algorithm (similar to rsync) to split large
>   files into chunks.  The most useful result of this is you can backup huge
>   virtual machine (VM) disk images, databases, and XML files incrementally,
>   even though they're typically all in one huge file, and not use tons of
>   disk space for multiple versions.
> - It uses the packfile format from git (the open source version control
>   system), so you can access the stored data even if you don't like bup's
>   user interface.
> - Unlike git, it writes packfiles *directly* (instead of having a separate
>   garbage collection / repacking stage) so it's fast even with gratuitously
>   huge amounts of data.  bup's improved index formats also allow you to
>   track far more filenames than git (millions) and keep track of far more
>   objects (hundreds or thousands of gigabytes).
> - Data is "automagically" shared between incremental backups without having
>   to know which backup is based on which other one - even if the backups
>   are made from two different computers that don't even know about each
>   other.  You just tell bup to back stuff up, and it saves only the minimum
>   amount of data needed.
> - You can back up directly to a remote bup server, without needing tons of
>   temporary disk space on the computer being backed up.  And if your backup
>   is interrupted halfway through, the next run will pick up where you left
>   off.  And it's easy to set up a bup server: just install bup on any
>   machine where you have ssh access.
> - Bup can use "par2" redundancy to recover corrupted backups even if your
>   disk has undetected bad sectors.
> - Even when a backup is incremental, you don't have to worry about
>   restoring the full backup, then each of the incrementals in turn; an
>   incremental backup *acts* as if it's a full backup, it just takes less
>   disk space.
> - You can mount your bup repository as a FUSE filesystem and access the
>   content that way, and even export it over Samba.
> - It's written in python (with some C parts to make it faster) so it's easy
>   for you to extend and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Backing up your Home folder would not backup the GRUB or the system files, for that you need to do a whole system backup.

You can do a whole system backup using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

To do that, first you would have to download the clonezilla ISO [from here.](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable)

After you have downloaded it, you will need to burn it to a CD.

Then you will have to boot from it to do the full system Backup.

The full procedure for it is given here-
http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php

You will have to choose the option **"Save disk image"**, the procedure for whic is given here-[http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php)

After you have made the backup, you can restore it using the option- **"Restore Disk Image"**, the procedure for which is given here- http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image

Look into it.
If you have any queries let us know.

Thank You!